# How to convert a zImage into uImage for booting with u-boot

Tags: u-boot

I have a zImage that I want to boot using u-boot.

I think zImage is not understood by u-boot,as I am getting the following error after uboot executes:

```
Wrong Image Format for bootm command
ERROR: can't get kernel image!
U-Boot-cortex>
```

Is there any tool that converts a zImage into uImage which u-boot understands?

Answer (score 8):

From a page on U-Boot images [here](http://www.trimslice.com/wiki/index.php/U-Boot_images#Creating_OS-kernel_images), the command you're looking for is :

```
mkimage -A arm -O linux -T kernel -C none -a 0x80008000 -e 0x80008000 -n "Linux kernel" -d arch/arm/boot/zImage uImage
```

The `mkimage` utility comes with the `u-boot-tools` package in Ubuntu (if that's what you're using), and it can be installed with the command `sudo apt-get install u-boot-tools`

Answer (score 4):

> In recent versions of U-Boot, you can simply enable the `bootz`
>   command,  which boots a raw zImage.
>
> And in order to enable the bootz command, you need to add:
>
> ```
> #define CONFIG_CMD_BOOTZ
> ```
>
> in your board config file (`include/configs/`)

Source http://u-boot.10912.n7.nabble.com/Booting-zImage-from-UBOOT-td150140.html